# Why is the position of the space (from str_locate() ) from the first row re-used for each subsequent row?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I do not understand why this does not return the first word in each sentence.
The position of the space from the first sentence seems to be re-used for each subsequent sentence.

What I instinctively tried:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data("sentences")

example <- tibble(sentence = sentences) %>% 
  mutate(firstword = trimws(str_sub(sentence, 
                             start = 1, 
                             end = str_locate(sentence, " ")[1])))
```

This solution, gives me what I want however, I try to avoid regex if I can.

```r
example <- tibble(sentence = sentences) %>% 
  mutate(firstword = str_extract(sentence, "[A-Za-z]+"))
```

Can someone explain why my first solution did not give me what I expected?

Thank you!

<sup>Created on 2020-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If it is to extract the first word, then `word(sentence, 1)` would be also used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str_locate` returns a `matrix` with two columns 'start', 'end'.  For subsetting the columns of `matrix`, use the `,` to separate the row/column index.  In the OP's code, it is getting the first element and not first column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(sentence = sentences) %>% 
   mutate(firstword = trimws(str_sub(sentence, 
                         start = 1, 
                         end = str_locate(sentence, " ")[, 1])))
# A tibble: 720 x 2
#   sentence                                    firstword
#   <chr>                                       <chr>    
# 1 The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.  The      
# 2 Glue the sheet to the dark blue background. Glue     
# 3 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.      It's     
# 4 These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.    These    
# 5 Rice is often served in round bowls.        Rice     
# 6 The juice of lemons makes fine punch.       The      
# 7 The box was thrown beside the parked truck. The      
# 8 The hogs were fed chopped corn and garbage. The      
# 9 Four hours of steady work faced us.         Four     
#10 Large size in stockings is hard to sell.    Large    
# … with 710 more rows
```

i.e. if we do

```
str_locate(head(sentences), " ")[1]
#[1] 4
```

returns a single element which gets recycled for all the rows and thus giving incorrect output

where as

```
str_locate(head(sentences), " ")[,1]
#[1] 4 5 5 6 5 4
```